# How to directly write to a JSON object (ObjectNode) from ObjectMapper in Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to output to a JSON object in Jackson JSON. However, I couldn't get the JSON object using the following code.

```
public class MyClass {

        private ObjectNode jsonObj;

        public ObjectNode getJson() {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              // some code to generate the Object user...
              mapper.writeValue(new File("result.json"), user);
              jsonObj = mapper.createObjectNode();
              return jsonObj;
        }

}
```

After the program runs, the file `result.json` contains the correct JSON data. However, `jsonObj` is empty (`jsonObj={}`). I looked up the Javadoc of [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) but couldn't find an easy way to write to a `ObjectNode` (JSON object in Jackson). There is no method in `ObjectMapper` like the following:

```
public void writeValue(ObjectNode json, Object value)
```

How to write to an `ObjectNode` directly from `ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make use of [ObjectMapper#valueToTree()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#valueToTree%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

> This will construct equivalent JSON Tree representation. Functionally same as if serializing value into JSON and parsing JSON as tree, but more efficient.

You don't need to write the `User` object out to a JSON file, if that's not required.

```
public class MyClass {

    private ObjectNode jsonObj;

    public ObjectNode getJson() {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      // some code to generate the Object user...
      JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(user);
      if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
        jsonObj = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
        return jsonObj;
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. And if output to a file is desired, `JsonNode` can be written into a file directly with `writeValue(file, jsonNode);`

Comment: anyidea how to publish the amount of written value using jackson?

Comment: the link here is dead